# Main function not outputting the text file lines

Tags: c++, console, getline

The following code is supposed to get a text file and read all its lines and print them put on console but although it properly saves the fname, it won't do anything after that. I appreciate if you could let me know what the problem is.

EDIT: To be more accurate, I will eventually want to call a few functions inside the else block but I first need to figure out why my program doesn't get to that point.

---

```C
int main()
{
    string fname = "", line, content;
    ifstream ifs; // input file stream
    string command = "";
    int k;
    cout << "---- Enter your command and the file name : ";
    while (getline(cin, line)){
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<line.length(); i++) {
            command += line[i];
            if (line[i] == ' ')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j<line.length(); j++)
        {
            fname += line[j];
        }
        cout << command;
    }

    if (command == "exit ")
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    // tries to open the file whose name is in string fname                 
    ifs.open(fname.c_str());

    if (ifs.fail()) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open file " << fname << endl;
        ifs.clear();
    }
    else { //do getline here to read content
        while (getline(ifs, content))
        {
            cout << "Content " << k++ << " : " << content << endl;
            //Call functions here later
        }
    }


    ifs.close(); // always remember to close it                         

    cout << "---- Enter another file and command name : ";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out myself. I was closing the while loop too early. It has to be closed after ifs.close(); instead.